# Circle alignment with tikz

Tags: venn-diagrams

I should end up with the first image but instead I get the second.
I've tried shifting the fill, but even the smallest change shifts it a ton.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-1.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5) node[below left]{$U$};
\fill[gray] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill[gray] (1,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node {$A$};
\draw (1.5,0) circle (1cm) node {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Correct Output]

[image: Incorrect Output]

Comment: Circles don't coincide because they have different coordinates. One at `(1,0)` and the second one at `(1.5,0)`.

Comment: Wow can't believe I didn't catch that! That's how it was coded in http://users.ju.edu/hduong/math220/venn_diagrams.pdf so I assumed it to be true. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-1.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5) node[below left]{$U$};
\fill[gray] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill[gray] (1,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node[xshift=-5mm] {$A$};
\draw (1,0) circle (1cm) node[xshift=5mm] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also want to use the following alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-1.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5) node[below left]{$U$};
\fill[gray] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill[gray] (1.5,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node {$A$};
\draw (1.5,0) circle (1cm) node {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a little too much intersection in this case. Is there a way to preserve the circle spacing?

Comment: @SethKillian Compile the second example.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll accept it in 3 minutes.